# How can I update a column in a table with the result of a select statement that uses row being updated as part of the where clause?

Tags: sql

This SQL statement example is very close to what I think I need...

```
 update table1 set value1 = x.value1 from 
      (select value1, code from table2 
       where code = something)  as x
```

However, what I need to do is change the "something" in the above example to a value from the row that is being updated.

For example, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
 update table1 A set value1 = x.value1 from 
      (select value1, code from table2 
       where code = A.something)  as x
```

This is a one time operation to update an existing table and I'm not really looking for high performance way to do this.  Any solution that gets the task done is good enough.

***Edit for clarification***

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 6.5.

***Edit***

I've since had several smart people tell me that many of the answers posted here *should* have worked.  My specific sql statement was way more convoluted than the pseudo sql I used in my example.  For some reason the answers I tried (most of them) did not work.  The same smart people couldn't figure out why they didn't work either.

The answer I selected did work for me.  Future answer seekers should probably look at several other answers below to help resolve their own questions, not just the one that solved my issue.

Comment: Is there any relation between Table1 and Table2? May be we can use INNER JOIN to join both to update a column in Table1. Let me know.

Comment: @Ashish - you pretty much got it in your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this :-

```
UPDATE table1 
SET x.Value1=y.Value1
FROM Table1 x INNER JOIN 
Table2 y ON x.Code=y.Something
```

Comment: This is ultimately what worked.  I had to move the "table1.something" outside the select, performing a join on the update part of the statment.  I'll post the working pseudo-sql in my question.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, no need to repost the pseudo-sql.  It looks like what you typed.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE is notoriously different across different DBMSes.  But try something along these lines:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Value1 =
  (SELECT Value1 FROM Table2 WHERE code = Table1.Something)
```

Comment: I tried this one too.  I get the message "The column prefix 'Table1' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query."  This is referring to the "Table1" in the select.

Comment: This is probably the most portable solution — it even works in Firebird, which doesn't support FROM in UPDATE at all.  I'm surprised it doesn't work in SQL Server 6.5; unfortunately, I don't have an installation handy to test against.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE table1 AS a
SET value1 = x.value1
FROM table2 AS x
WHERE x.code = a.something
```

Comment: Actually I think that this one should work if both "as"s are removed. You can't alias a table that's being updated, and you don't need "as" to alias a table name that is in a "from" statement.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it should work like this:

```
Update table1 Set value1 = 
( Select value1
  From table2 
  Where table2.code = table1.something
)
```

Comment: This is similar to my very first attempt.  I get an "Incorrect syntax near 'A'." when I try this.

Comment: @Sailing Judo: I have edited my answer, but now it's more or less the same as Larry Lustig's. In case `table1` is not your real table name, are you sure you replaced both in the first and in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table1.Value1 = Table2.Value1
WHERE Table2.Code = Table1.Something
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
update table1
set value1 = x.value1
from table2 x
where something = x.code
```

Answer (score -1):

"I am using Microsoft SQL Server 6.5"??
Why?
Why don't you get the FREE SQL 2008 Express edition or if you qualify, SQL 2008 Developers Edition for about USD50?

Comment: @Johan van Zyl: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you did not provide an answer, you should have added this as comment to the question instead of answer.

Comment: Who knows.  Maybe the database is embedded in some sailing hardware?  One doesn't get far in this business if one's solution to a programming problem involves purchasing new hardward and/or software.

Comment: This is an existing database server that works perfectly fine.  I'm pretty sure the Express versions (which I use all the time) don't support hundreds of connections needed by the applications involved here.